# dtrace java API on Oracle Solaris?

Tags: java, solaris, dtrace

I would like to use dtrace from a Java application on machine running Solaris Sparc. I have seen examples of the DTrace Java API in a few places including here:

https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/using_dtrace_java_api

and here:

ftp://ida.esac.esa.int/.SUNWnative/usr/share/lib/java/javadoc/dtrace/html/fast.html

But what I cannot figure out is whether the dtrace Java API is available only on some variant of Solaris (like OpenSolaris).

Can I use the dtrace Java API on Oracle Solaris running on Sun Sparc hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/819-2183/auto9/index.html), the DTrace Java toolkit is located at `/usr/share/lib/java`.

> The Java Dynamic Tracing (DTrace) API is an interface to the native
>   DTrace library. This interface provides support to develop
>   visualization tools written in Java. The Java DTrace API comes
>   installed in **/usr/share/lib/java/dtrace.jar**. This API allows multiple
>   consumers of DTrace data to run simultaneously within a single Virtual
>   Machine for the Java platform (JVMTM machine). Each consumer of the
>   Java DTrace API listens for probe data and enables you to request
>   consistent snapshots of aggregation data at any time.
>
> For more information, see the JavadocTM API at
>   **/usr/share/lib/java/javadoc/dtrace/api/index.html**.

On my install of Solaris 11.2, the files are exactly where the document says they will be.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I couldn't see the dtrace.jar, so I upgraded my Solaris to 10/13, and they are there.